# Copying LibreOffice from DMG to local SSD takes 35 minutes - cp takes 3 minutes

Tags: mac, ssd, speed, finder, cp

Today I downloaded the latest version of LibreOffice for my Mac. After downloading, I opened the DMG file and copied the app-folder to the Applications. This took 35 minutes for a 700 MB folder. At 250MB and 670MB the copying was very slow, like 200KB per second. Copying from 250MB to 300MB took like ten minutes.

Right after this completed, I opened the terminal and copied the same LibreOffice.app folder to the SSD, and it took less than three minutes.

What makes the Finder taking so long to copy a folder?

Comment: I just saw this same behavior and went looking for an explanation and ended up here.  It appears that this is an issue known to the LibreOffice developers and testers, too, but no one so far has provided an explanation.  Hopefully someone can enlighten us.